# I cannot find an app

Tags: games

I had an app on my ipad a while ago. I cant remember the name of it, but I can explain it.

It starts with thousands of moving specs. You can change the amount of dots, the thickness, color etc.. you can also made them move in different ways by the placement of your fingers.

Does anybody know what I'm talking about and can you help me out?

Comment: let us know what app was it when you find it! :D

Comment: I have that on my iPad.  It was one of the very early apps to use multi touch in an interesting way. To adjust the thickness and color of the boids you'd use all ten fingers.  One finger would shoot boids away from it.  Two would capture boids nearby, three would capture and spin all boids, 5 would pause all boids, etc. I don't recall the name at the moment, but it has been updated in the last two years, so it may still be available and searchable on the store. I still have it loaded on my ipad, but that's not with me at the moment, so if I don't post an answer in a day or two, remind me.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the App Store app, then Purchased tab and select Not in this iPad.

This is a list of apps that you used on that iPad and is not installed nowadays. That list should list your program.

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds to me like Uzu, by colordodge labs. It's changed since you last saw it, but the initial basic mode is the same, and produces this sort of display:

[image: yellow-green dots on screen]

Comment: Yes Uzu. That's it. I knew it had an odd name. Thank you!!